# BB 10 Development Environment

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Hello Everybody ,
                 I am using following tools & SDK for Blackberry Native development in Windows

1. 10 Native SDK 10.0.9.1673
2. BlackBerry10Simulator-Installer-BB10_0_10
3. Virtual Machine VMware-player-4.0.3-703057

Let me know, following configuration is correct for BB Cascaded Development.
Because I am getting the following problems

1. "ldd:FATAL: Unresolved symbol "_ZN2bb8cascades11QmlDocumentC1Ev" called from Executable"   error when I am trying to run binaries on
   simulator.
2. If I import a BB Cascaded sample project in SDk then "BAR PACKAGES" Folder show by default , if I create my own project then
   "BAR PACKAGES" then it will not show .

---

[image]

Actually it's not a answer I don't have any choice for image post that's why I follow this way ,here I am showing you the Snapshot of my QNX-IDE , I have imported  GoodCitizen & Falling Blocks from sample projects . Good-Citizen Project is working fine compile as well as run on Virtual Machine. But in the Falling Blocks Project no BAR Packages create why this is happening , can any one explain me the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared your QML Document in either your main.cpp or app.cpp?

```
QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///main.qml").parent(this);
```

Comment: @ I tried the things  that you told but getting Compile time error , Is the above mentioned configuration is correct for BB10 development?

Comment: The FallingBlocks image doesn't have any QML files from what I can tell, so I'm not sure how you got the original problems you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update api level

1. help-->updade api levels & install new software
2. Keep on update your tools to avoid errors